# VLOOKUP SUMPRODUCT Combination

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 3 pages in an excel document.

1st consists of **`Distributor(name)`**, **`Genre`** and **`Profit`**

2nd has **`Distributor`**(name) and **`Location`**(Australia or Overseas)

3rd is where I need to input that data to show for each Genre based on the distributors Location, how much each genre profits.

So, the 3rd page table looks something like this

```
|...........|Australian|Overseas|
|Genre |
|Music |
|Action|
|Total..|..................|...............|
```

So what I need accomplished is to have for each genre the profit made based on the distributor location, Australian or Overseas.

I am not sure how to get this, I've tried `IF((SUMPRODUCT))` and `IF(VLOOKUP())` but no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF `Dist1` is the Distributor range from sheet 1 and `Dist2` the one on sheet 2...... and sheet 3 table starts at A1 then use this "array formula" in B3

`=SUM(SUMIFS(Profit,Genre,$A3,Dist1,IF(Location=B$1,Dist2)))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied across and down

See example [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ghj79ebssit1ph1/Movies.xlsx)

Note that I used named ranges but you can use cell reference instead if required

Comment: Could you help me out by telling me what Profit, Genre, and Location represent? Are they the ranges?...if so, I have tried this and it does not work.

Comment: This is what I have tried, using sumproduct instead of sumifs because I am using openoffice at the moment:

=SUM(SUMPRODUCT(Stock.W4:W36;Stock.K4:K36;"Australian";Stock.E4:E36;IF("Australian"=Distributor.D4:D9;Distributor.A4:A9)))

Comment: I posted an example with SUMIFS - I used named ranges for simplicity but you can use specific ranges. Without SUMIFs the syntax will be different - in Excel you can use this version `=SUM(IF(Genre=$A3,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Dist1,IF(Location=B$1,Dist2),0)),Profit)))` which is an "array formula" too - I don't know if the syntax differs for Open Office

Answer (score 0):

Put an extra column on your Sht 1 with a `VLookup` to return the Location from Sht 2.

Then on sht 3 use `SUMIFS` to get the totals (assuming Excel 2007+) or `SUMPRODUCT` (Excel 2003)

Comment: Is there any other way to do it without altering Sheet 1?